# PHP Projects in apache2 are not displaying in http://localhost/, php projects are stored in /var/www/html

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

PHP projects are not displaying from `http://localhost/` I have stored all php projects in `/var/www/html` folder. I am using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: what you are getting instead?

Comment: only .html file it is displaying 
php projects are not displaying

Comment: By "not displaying" do you mean you get an error such as a 404, or no output? Look at the browser's page source -  do you see your PHP source code there?  If so, then Apache is not handing the code to PHP for execution.

Comment: not 404 error, whole project folders only not coming in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the permission of your project folder to read and write.Then it will display in your localhost.

Comment: Thanx Nayeem for your answer